# Removing maven files from module

Tags: maven

Is it okay to remove the following two files from the package module:

```
mvnw
mvnw.cmd
```

Our project is dockerized in a network.
Does this deletion affect the future deployment processes and what's the purpose of it?

Comment: anyone could help about this maven and java project?

Answer (score 1):

mvnw is the maven wrapper.
It is useful if you need a specific version of maven to build your project or to be able to build it from a place where maven is not installed.

should not impact future deployment if you delete it.

Comment: yes, i also point maven versions into every module's Dockerfiles, so if I delete them, version can be taken from dockerfile on build and compose?

Comment: mvnw is something you use instead of mvn, if your dockerfiles use mvn, you do not need mvnw.

Comment: so i need to delete mvnw and leave mvn file?

Comment: you don't need to, but you can. If you already have mvn in there, you do not need mvnw. Deleting it will not affect anything, except maybe size, but to a very small part.